# Why my theme suddenly gone blue after an update?

Tags: blocks, theming, updating

After updating the Bartik 960 template on Drupal the homepage highlight each of the blocks on the page in blue. It looks like it's gone into a debugging mode, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

[image: Website with blue screen indicating blocks]

Answer (score 0):

Check the css with your browser's inspector and see what elements are surrounding this behavior.  Is this occurring for all users (admin to anonymous)?

Does this happen in all regions or just the "highlight" region?

Comment: It recurs for all regions and for all users. It seems like it has something to do with the Nice Menu getting bumped down. I can't find anything in the module that allows me to change its location, though.

Comment: My quick fix would be to restore the theme from a backup and diff the style sheets until you find the culprit.